# express a set using countable intersections/unions

Tags: set-theory

Let $f,g:[0,1]→[0,1]$
be two functions over the unit interval. Express the set $\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)>g(x)\}$
using countable unions, intersection and complements of sets of the form $A_i=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)>a_i\}$
and $B_i=\{x\in[0,1]:g(x)<b_i\}$
. Hint: choose $a_i$
and $b_i$
to be suitable rational numbers.

I tried to take the intersection points between the functions as $A_i$ and $B_i$, but I didnt succeed to prove its correct.

Comment: Hi @ron and welcome to Math StackExchange! Please format the math in your question using MathJax, [here's how](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, please show your work so far, otherwise this question may be closed.

Comment: Please don't delete and repost closed questions. You should edit them instead.